# Adding an asynchronous call to google diff match patch, a synchonously built library

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, diff, patch

I'm trying to adjust the [diff match patch google javascript library](http://code.google.com/p/google-diff-match-patch/) to make one of its calls asynchronous. The problem is that the entire library is built synchronously so that closures return objects rather then sending them through executed callback functions. I'd like to make one of the functions asynchronous without having to rewrite the entire library, which would be an enormous task because it would require rewriting every method up the stack (since the library is very modular). Instead, I would like to make one call asynchronous with setTimeout that sets the data I want to return to an appropriately scoped variable. Then the function waiting for that data would loop until it received it. Is this a reliable way to handle this, and will it work? What's a good practice for this?

Comment: The only benefit I can see in placing the call in a `setTimeout` is if you need to make several such calls and want to give the browser a chance to refresh its display between calls. But the concept of having a function waiting in a loop won't work with single-threaded JS: you'd need to supply a callback function that is called from within the function you pass to `setTimeout` once there is a result. (Or perhaps I haven't understood what you mean - I'd suggest showing a little bit of code for the approach you are suggesting.)

Comment: Have a look at the Promise pattern: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2011/09/11/asynchronous-programming-in-javascript-with-promises.aspx

Comment: @nnnnnn yes, that's exactly the reason why i want to use `setTimeout`. IE is locking up and I want the user to be able to do things while it is processing the diff. I understand that the right way to do it is to pass in a cb function and execute it in setTimeout. The problem with that, though, is that I'd need to rewrite the other functions up the call stack to handle callbacks too, and since the library is very modular and tangled, this would bea nightmare...

Comment: If a _single_ call to the diff function takes long enough that IE locks up then `setTimeout` won't help because the user can do things only while no JS is running (even if the JS is started by a timeout). The diff function would need to be refactored to do its processing in discrete chunks. If you need _multiple_ calls where each one is reasonably quick _then_ you'd get a benefit from putting each call in a timeout.

Comment: @nnnnnn I isolated the bottleneck to one `for` loop. I think that if that loop uses recursion with `setTimeout` in batches, the UI may be freed up

Comment: OK then, yes, that should help.

Comment: @nnnnnn so how about having a `setInterval` loop every X milliseconds in the synchronous part of the app that waits for the `setTimeout` to store the data into a variable that both parts of the app has access to? I think it would need to uniquely mark each "thread" and also increment a counter for the number of "threads" it was waiting on... would this work?